# Problem with \mathsf

Tags: amsmath

[image]I have a weird problem that I can't seem to figure out. In a beamer document I use `\mathsf` to specify how I want some of the text to appear. The specific command is

`$\mathsf{ASG}_{1}=\sigma_{\mathsf{ENO} \leq \mathsf{“E3”}}(\mathsf{ASG})$`

which puts in a `\` after `\leq` and before `E3`as shown in the attached figure. I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
 $\mathsf{ASG}_{1}=\sigma_{\mathsf{ENO} \leq \mathsf{“E3”}}(\mathsf{ASG})$
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use arbitrary symbols inside \mathXX. Better switch to text mode then.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike -- can you clarify what you mean by "arbitrary symbols"? The only thing I have inside \mathsf is text -- no symbols as far as I can see.

Comment: You have quotes.

Comment: In case you don't know, there is the command `\text{}` from `amsmath`.

Comment: Many thanks Ulrike and Sigur -- those are helpful. I was not aware of \text{}. I'll try that.

Comment: For the double quotes, it is better to use `\text{``E3''}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can define math symbols for the quotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathopenquotes}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"5C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mathclosedquotes}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"22}

\newcommand{\quoted}[1]{\mathopenquotes{#1}\mathclosedquotes}

\begin{document}

$\mathsf{ASG}_{1}=\sigma_{\mathsf{ENO} \leq \mathsf{\quoted{E3}}}(\mathsf{ASG})$

$A_{1}=\sigma_{E\le\quoted{E3}} B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: this assumes your math alphabets are taken from OT1 encoded fonts.

Comment: Thank you; this is interesting to know. For this case, I just used \text{} rather than \mathsf and it is sufficient. But for more complex cases, I'll keep your suggestion in mind.